# Multiple If And Statements

Tags: excel

I am a novice excel user so I'll explain this the best I can.  I need to track Returns, Returns/Exchanges and who processed each...

Cell column A Contains employee Names
Cell column B is where return information will go
Cell column C is where exchange information will go

In B2 I want a formula that will say, if A11:A300 contains 'Ben', and F11:F300 contains 'return', then E11:E300

Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if you're attempting to "count" all instances of "Ben" and "return" and collect the total in B2, or if you want to return the value of E11:E300 in B11:B300 when the condition that each row that containing "Ben" and "return" is met.

If it's the former, the this should do it:

```
=SUM(($A11:$A300="Ben")*($F11:$F300="return"))
```

Just enter that formula into cell B2 and hold "Ctrl + Shift" while you hit "Enter." That will create an array formula that will count all instances of "Ben" and "return" for each row. You'll know you did it right if the formula is surrounded by curly braces {}. And, no, you cannot manually add them. You must use the entry combination: Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

If it's the latter, then this should do it:

```
=IF(AND($A11="Ben", $F11="return"),$E11,"")
```

You could do this more efficiently with an array formula (as specified above), but it's a bit more complicated and I don't want to confuse you since you're an admitted "novice."

Just enter that formula into cell B11 and then drag and copy it down to the remaining 299 rows. This will return the value of E11:E300 in B11:B300 as you requested in your question.

If it's something other than that, then you need to rephrase your question.